# Xcode 6 - Adding a label outside of UITableView scroll range

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrollview, tableview

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this. Maybe I haven't worded the question right (if that's the case, then sorry). Basically what I want to add to my table view, is a label, that is outside of the scroll range. Not easy to explain, but here's an example from Snapchat:
(Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5dzm.png)

As you can see, it's a normal table view controller, at the bottom of the scroll. However, when you stretch the scroll further, you can see a hidden label:
(Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYxu0.png)

I can recreate this effect in a scroll view, however I'm having trouble with it in the table views. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use sections to design as per your requirement and header titles.

If you just want section header title, you can use UITableViewDataSource method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Or you can set you custom view as header using UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

The controller implementing these, needs to be the delegate/datasource of your table view.